# Subclass __init__ is not called if superclass __new__ is defined

Tags: python

See the following ipython session:

```
$ ipython --no-banner

In [1]: class foo(object):
   ...:     def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         print 'in superclass __new__'
   ...:         return self
   ...: 
   ...: class bar(foo):
   ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         print 'in subclass __init__'
   ...:         self.val = 42
   ...:         

In [2]: b = bar()
in superclass __new__

In [3]: b.val
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c55d38c9d4d9> in <module>()
----> 1 b.val

AttributeError: type object 'bar' has no attribute 'val'
```

What is going on here? Why does defining `__new__` in `foo` prevent the `__init__` from running in `bar`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__ “If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.”

Comment: Just a conceptual misconception: `__new__` doesn't take a `self`, because `self` doesnt exist at this point. `self` is what's going to be returned by `__new__`, which will then be passed on to `__init__` for initialization

Comment: `__new__` is special-cased to be a class method without having to decorate it as such. The first argument (conventionally) should be `cls`, because `foo.__new__` gets `foo` as its first argument, not an instance of `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning an invalid value from `__new__`.  Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked ... If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Note that the first argument to `__new__` is a class, not an object. `__new__`'s job is to allocate the object, often by calling `super().__new__`.

Try this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'in superclass __new__'
        return super(foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'in subclass __init__'
        self.val = 42

b = bar()
print b
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) documentation:

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

So, try again like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'in superclass __new__'
        return super(foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'in subclass __init__'
        self.val = 42
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `__new__` function signature implies you don't quite understand what is going on. The first argument to `__new__` will be the *class*, calling it `self` which is conventionally used for the *instance* should be a warning: `__new__` is a constructor, the instance *doesn't exist yet*. So what happens is you are returning an object that isn't the same type as the class, (it *is* the class in fact, so it is of type `type`) thus, `__init__` is skipped! You want something like this:

```
In [4]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         print 'in superclass __new__'
   ...:         return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   ...:
   ...: class Bar(Foo):
   ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         print 'in subclass __init__'
   ...:         self.val = 42
   ...:

In [5]: b = Bar()
in superclass __new__
in subclass __init__
```